# Extract multiple occurrences of a Substring from a text file

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file that contains multiple occurrences of a substring - pin="`*****`" where * equals a number.

The pin number inside the enclose quotes can be N length.

What I would like to do is extract the line `pin="*****"` or even better just the number inside it and add it to an array for later processing.

An example of what the text file looks like is like so

```
[123456]
mystring="srthjkgnyjh"
pin="9898
anotherstring="jghksdfghjkdfg6788678345hjkfsd"

[654321]
mystring="hksfkhjsjl"
pin="4343434"
anotherstring="kdgig89794578945789jkhflsf7865"
```

etc..

Ideas are much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=\bpin=")[0-9]+(?=")~', $str, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
```

`(?<=..)` and `(?=..)` are a lookbehind and a lookahead. You can find more informations about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).